# Will the selenium IDE wait for timeout or execute the next command after 1000milliseconds(Setspeed)?

Tags: selenium, timeout, selenium-ide

If the setspeed is 1000milliseconds and default timeout is 30000milliseconds. Will the selenium IDE wait for timeout or execute the next command after 1000milliseconds?

Answer (score 0):

http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.com/2013/03/use-of-setspeed-and-settimeout-commands.html

> "setSpeed" Command setup the delay between tow command execution or we can say it is useful to managing the execution speed of  selenium. By default there is not any such delay but if your application is slow then you have to use "setSpeed" Command in your sript. - See more at: http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.com/2013/03/use-of-setspeed-and-settimeout-commands.html#sthash.frfeBCFD.dpuf

.

> "setTimeout" command controlling the timeout period for the action to complete. - See more at: http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.com/2013/03/use-of-setspeed-and-settimeout-commands.html#sthash.frfeBCFD.dpuf

So if I understand what you're asking: Each command will be, at a minimum, 3000 ms apart. So if you do two echo statements you will see the first one at 0s and then 3s later, the 2nd command:

```
<tr>
    <td>setSpeed</td>
    <td>3000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

With the timeout, if you do an AndWait command, it will wait until the command is true OR the timeout period elapses. This can be best seen on a page load (which has an implicit wait):

```
<tr>
    <td>setTimeout</td>
    <td>5000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>https://httpbin.org/delay/6</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

> [info] Executing: |setTimeout | 5000 | |
>
> [info] Executing: |open | https://httpbin.org/delay/6 | |
>
> [error] Timed out after 5000ms

So yes, the timeout will be respected BEFORE it tries to load the next command.